# Некорректная работа обработчика ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема. Если добавить запись а после этого сделать обновление страницы. То почему то ещё раз срабатывает обработчик кнопки сохранения данных и те же самые данные ещё раз сохраняются в бд. То есть запись дублируется. Из за чего так может происходить? Почему при обновлении страницы кнопкой f5 обработчик срабатывает ещё раз?

Comment: Прикрепи пожалуйста код))

Comment: Код экшна контроллера (в который ведет форма) в студию! Форма, кстати, тоже может пригодиться. И какой именно фреймворк используется поверх ASP.NET?

Comment: @free_ze проблема вот в чём. Если я просто обнавляю страницу нечего не сделав перед этим. То есть зашёл на неё и тыкаю f5. То это не пост бек. Но если я например сначала сделаю добавление или любое другое действие. Тогда при обновлении страницы, код проходит условие `IsPostBack` и в реквест парамс возвращает мне последнее моё действие и как следствие срабатывает последний заюзанный мной перед обновлением страницы обработчик. В чём тут может быть проблема? Не чиститься пост бек запрос или что?

Comment: Потому что F5 в вашем браузере повторяет последний отправленный запрос. Это нормально для бразузеров. Вам надо либо делать запросы через ajax, либо обновлять страницу в браузере через ctrl+f5 (или shift+f5, не помню точно)

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо. А при ajax запросах, браузер не повторяет последний пост бек запрос?

Comment: @Андрей браузер не повторяет ajax запросы. Потому если вы получате/отправляете данные только ajax запросами, то можно смело жать F5, иначе жмите shift+f5

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за подсказку.